# Is it possible for Sass to bypass a code block?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is there any way to instruct Sass (or Compass) not to compile a block of code (e.g. a hack for IE) but write directly into the resulted css file?

**Answer:**
For those who asked me what exactly the code is, I don't remember because I saw it from a random site, but it looks a lot like a command, not css style

But I've figured out the solution. We can use a Sass function unquote() to add a random string  as css property value without being alerted as error. For example, Compass used this in their opacity() mixin:

```
filter: unquote("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=#{round($opacity * 100)})");
```

Comment: What do you mean by this?  Why would you want something in the CSS file that is not compiled?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not. Further, function calls inside CSS comments ( /* comment */ ) will still get compiled! When I write comments to myself about what a function that I wrote and what it does, I notice that if my output does not strip the comments out, it will compile them (or error on them if the comment sample contains only a sample variable).

If the code is valid-ish CSS there is no reason why Compass would mess with it. If it is a hack for IE that needs to be there, it will still be there in the output. What is the code and what is the error that it is producing?